# Netty CorruptedFrameException with multiple connection packets arrive at the same time

Tags: java, exception, frame, netty, decoder

I am encountering a very weird issue with my program which is using Netty.

I am listening to a port and parsing the messages (using FrameDecoder implementation). Everything is working fine if I am receiving one connection, but when I am receiving two connections on the same port (each one from a different server), I encounter a rare but critical situation where I get corruptedFrameException

The issue occurs when my program receives TCP packets with the exact same timestamp (when sending information at a very high rate) as follows

1. TCP Packet from Server 1
2. TCP Packet from Server 2
3. TCP Packet from Server 1 (which is a continutation of the message started in bullet 1)
4. TCP Packet from Server 2 (which is a continuation of the message starged in bullet 2)

My program tries to parse 1 and 2 as a message, instead of knowing that the actual message is 1 & 3 and 2 & 4
I read somewhere that maybe I need to instantiate a new FrameDecoder for every channel connection, but I don't know how exactly to do that. I am adding the decoder to the pipleline at startup and I cannot figure out how to add a new one to a specific channel

The exceptions I am experiencing are:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.CorruptedFrameException: Adjusted frame length (0) is less than lengthFieldEndOffset: 2
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:340) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:282) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:214) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:345) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:332) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:323) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:275) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:196) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:651) [na:1.5.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:676) [na:1.5.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595) [na:1.5.0]
```

and

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 4096: 8224
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:282) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:345) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:332) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:323) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:275) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:196) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46) ~[netty-3.1.5.GA.jar:]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:651) [na:1.5.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:676) [na:1.5.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595) [na:1.5.0]
```

Comment: "maybe I need to instantiate a new FrameDecoder for every channel". No maybe about it. That's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I figured, but how do I do it?
I am adding the decoded on the ChannelPipeLine object.addLast("decoder", decoderObject) upon initialization,
but when a new channel is connecting I am at the point of channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent t) ...
If I instantiate a new decoder, how do I assign it to the channel?
Something is missing in the puzzle :)

Comment: That's the channelpipelinefactory's job. Define one that creates your decoder and then either use a bootstrap (with the channel factory) or pass the pipeline factory to the channel factory when requesting a new channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a **new** object of frame decoder to your **new**(second?) channel. Duplicate exception is because you are using the same channel.

1. The server bootstrap takes a pipeline factory which will configure all new channels with the appropriate encoders and decoders.
2. Whenever a remote client connects to your server it creates it own channel object.
3. In the Channel PipelineFactory implementation you are using. Make sure that **new instance** of frame decoder is created each time pipeline() method is invoked.
4. The @Sharable annotation is for documentation purpose only. Even if you use it, it will not affect anything, since it is not code/logic. Just a marker that is all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "NOT share" the FrameDecoder between channels. FrameDecoder is not not annotated with @Sharable so you can't share it. Thats the cause of your Problem here..

Comment: Thanks. However, there is no @Sharable annotation in my code, still it happens. I'm trying to see how to implement what the folks in the comments above suggested, but still no luck :)

Comment: If you can link to an example of how to add FrameDecoder to the channel itself and not the pipeline (or am I missing something in my understanding), or do I need to create a whole new pipeline? I have tried doing channel.getPipeLine().addLast("decoder",new object) but I get a "duplicate" exception